# Error while trying to run MLPack from source

Tags: c++, machine-learning, boost, ndk-build, mlpack

OS:Linux

Compile: NDK-Build

I am facing error while I try to compile `mlPack` from source. The code works fine when I run by installing the `mlPack`and it's dependencies(`armadillo`, `ensmallen`, `boost`). But I am trying to create a single `*.so` and `*.a` file of the following files(`mlpack_test.cpp`, `mlpack_test.hpp`) and the `mlPack` library  together. And the error occurs while trying that.

**mlPack_test.hpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "mlpack/core.hpp"
#include "mlpack/methods/random_forest/random_forest.hpp"
#include "mlpack/methods/decision_tree/random_dimension_select.hpp"
#include "mlpack/core/cv/k_fold_cv.hpp"
#include "mlpack/core/cv/metrics/accuracy.hpp"
#include "mlpack/core/cv/metrics/precision.hpp" 
#include "mlpack/core/cv/metrics/recall.hpp"

using namespace arma;
using namespace mlpack;
using namespace mlpack::tree;
using namespace mlpack::cv;

using namespace std;

void Test();
```

**mlPack_test.cpp**

```
#include "mlpack_test.hpp"

void Test()
{
    string save_model_path = "model.bin";

    string sample = "1265,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0";
    mat dataset(sample);
    Row<size_t> labels;
    labels = conv_to<Row<size_t>>::from(dataset.row(dataset.n_rows - 1));
    dataset.shed_row(dataset.n_rows - 1);

    const size_t numClasses = 5;
    const size_t minimumLeafSize = 5;
    const size_t numTrees = 50;

    RandomForest<GiniGain, RandomDimensionSelect> rf;
    rf = RandomForest<GiniGain, RandomDimensionSelect>(dataset, labels,
        numClasses, numTrees, minimumLeafSize);

    Row<size_t> predictions;
    rf.Classify(dataset, predictions);
    const size_t correct = arma::accu(predictions == labels);
    cout << "\nTraining Accuracy: " << (double(correct) / double(labels.n_elem))<<endl;
    mlpack::data::Save(save_model_path, "model", rf, false);

}
```

**Error**

Whenever I try to create the `*.so` or `*.a` file using `ndk-build`, the following error occurs:

[image]
[image]

The `Android.mk` file is as following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := hello-jni-prebuilt
CODE_PATH := .
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mlpack_test.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

All the files including library folders are in the `LOCAL_PATH`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by using -frtti and -exception CPP flags in Android.mk file